# Calendar Webpart

Tags: 2007, calendar, web-part

My calendar WebPart is showing three columns in Day view and Week view. Month view is just fine. If I go directly to the list page, it's shown just fine. I tried creating a new calendar view and the same thing happens. Here is a screen shot of the Week View
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e858a96927.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e858a96927.png)

Comment: Can you provide the actual screenshot ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the Zone property to "Header".